# Case Comment - Customer Notification

Tags: trigger, force.com, case, case-object

I have a trigger written which is copying comments from a Custom Object (Timesheet) to the CaseComment object.. I am marking them as 'IsPublished = true'

The problem is that email notifications are not being sent to the Contact for any comments that are copied with this trigger. 
But any manually created comments are notified to the Contact.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: what in your setup causes CaseComment emails to be sent to the Contact? For example, using workflows? or using a switch in `Case Settings`?

Comment: I think this is standard functionality .. Whenever you add a public case comment from the UI on any case, it sends out the communication

Comment: Please check: `Case | Settings | Enable Case Comment Notification to Contacts`; please check Workflows on `Case` and `CaseComment`. This is all configurable so there's really no 'standard functionality'

Comment: Yeah but that's not my question

Comment: Maneesh -- just trying to understand how emails get sent, since you didn't post the trigger code, I'm assuming that emails are sent by either a workflow or the Case Setting and are not manually sent from Apex;  Sorry if I misunderstood

Comment: You are right .. In this case, it is the case settings .. But that works only for actions happening on the UI and not through Apex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled it using trigger only. Below is the code

```
 if(!PublicComments.isEmpty())
       {

         System.debug('Entering Bllock - Public Comments Not Empty');

         Database.insert(PublicComments);
         System.debug('TS Comments inserted successfully as Public Comments');
         System.debug('Starting Email Sending Loop');

         for(integer i = 0; i < PublicComments.size(); i++) 
         {
           Case newcase = [Select ContactID, casenumber from Case Where ID = :PublicComments[i].parentID]; // getting the Contact ID & CaseNumber
           System.debug('Newcase - ');
           System.debug(newcase);
           System.debug(newcase.casenumber);
           System.debug(newcase.ContactID);

           If (newcase.ContactID != null)  // there could be cases with no associated contact
           {

              Contact newcontact = [Select Email from Contact Where ID = :newcase.ContactID]; // get the email of the Contact
              System.debug('NewContact - ');
              System.debug(newcontact);             

              If (newcontact.Email != null)  // there might not be any email address for a Contact
              {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                message.setSubject('A new Case Comment has been posted '+newcase.casenumber);
                message.setPlainTextBody('Case Number: '+newcase.casenumber+' - '+PublicComments[i].CommentBody);
                message.setToAddresses(new String[] { newcontact.Email });

                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] {message});
              }
           }

        }

        System.debug('EXIT the block - Public Comments Not Empty');             
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be your issue.

Personally, I find that the `Setup | Case | Support Settings` check boxes don't always do what you think they will do under all use cases - Web to Case, Email To Case, and direct user interaction with the OOB Case UI.

In one of my orgs, after some frustration, I did the following for a consistent Case Comment email experience

1. Added two custom Checkbox fields on Case: `HasNewPublicCaseComment__c` and `HasNewPrivateCaseComment__c`
2. Two workflows on `CaseComment` to set the corresponding fields on Case
3. Workflow on `Case` with criteria `HasPublicCaseComment__c = true`.
4. The Case workflow does the Email Alert using the merge field for the most recent case comment and resets the `HasNewPublicCaseComment__` to false. Case email alerts have access to more email recipients than CaseComment email alerts

Notes:

1. Assumes that CaseComments aren't uploaded for the same Case in bulk in one transaction

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in [DMLOptions Email Header](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_EmailHeader.htm) is not enabled while you are inserting your case comment in your trigger.

You should be doing something like this before calling insert operation on case comment instance

```
Database.DMLOptions opts = new Database.DMLOptions();
opts.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = true;
opts.EmailHeader.triggerOtherEmail = true;
opts.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
Databse.insert(myComment,opts);
```

Edit:

After looking through comments, i googled and found [this SFSE question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9469/sending-customer-notification-case-comment-through-apex-trigger) which mentions this cannot be achieved. As a workaround,

1. Insert case comments using your trigger.
2. On insert of case comment, write a workflow to update a field (say a
   check box called "send email notification" on the case).
3. On the case, write a workflow email alert to notifying the contact
   when the "send email notifcation" is updated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Vignesh, Below is my code  

`    if(!PublicComments.isEmpty())
     {
    Database.DMLOptions opts = new Database.DMLOptions();
    opts.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = true;
    opts.EmailHeader.triggerOtherEmail = true;
    opts.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
    PublicComments.setOptions(opts);
    Database.insert(PublicComments);
    }  `

I am getting an error saying "Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [List<CaseComment>].setOptions(Database.DMLOptions) at line 88 column 14"

Comment: Sorry my bad. You should be using Database.insert by passing the casecomment instance and the dmloptions instance. Updated my answer.

Comment: Ok.. Did that and saved the trigger. But still no emails are coming through ..

Comment: Does it work for CaseComment object ?